# Error 404 Not Found When turning pages in pagination in page Archiver product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm getting a 404 error when using Wordpress and Woocommerce at same time.I paginate the products in the archive page but when I switch to other pages except the first page, I get a 404 error.
This is the code of the archive-product.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://woo.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.4.0
 */

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;
get_header('shop');
global $wp_query;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged') != 0 && is_int(get_query_var('paged'))) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged,
];
query_posts(array_merge($args, $wp_query->query)); ?>

<div class="archive_product_container">
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
     */
    woocommerce_output_content_wrapper();

    //do_action('woocommerce_before_main_content');
    ?>
    <?php
    if (woocommerce_product_loop()) {
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
         */
        do_action("woocommerce_before_shop_loop");
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
        if (have_posts()) {
            while (have_posts()) {
                the_post();

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
                 */
                do_action('woocommerce_shop_loop');

                wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
            }
            wp_reset_postdata(); // Đặt ngay sau vòng lặp while
        }


        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
         */
        $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if ($total_pages > 1) {
            $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
            paginate($current_page, $wp_query);
        }
        do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop');
    } else {
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
         *
         * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
         */
        do_action('woocommerce_no_products_found');
    }
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action('woocommerce_after_main_content');
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_sidebar.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */ ?>
    <div class="filter">
        <h2>Bộ lọc</h2>
        <hr>
        <?php do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');
        ?>
    </div>

</div>
<?php get_footer('shop');
```

And here is the code of the page transfer link fuction

```
function paginate($current_page, $query = null)
{
    $pages = $query->max_num_pages;
    echo '<div class="pagination">';
    echo '<div class="prev-next-links">';
    if ($current_page > 1) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($current_page - 1) . '" class="prev"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i></a>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="page-numbers">';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($i) . '" class="page-number ' . ($current_page == $i ? 'current' : '') . '">' . $i . '</a>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="prev-next-links">';
    if ($current_page < $pages) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($current_page + 1) . '" class="next"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i></a>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I tried change from paged to page but the result is still error 404